# Running reviewtool command in C#

Tags: c#

i need to run this review tool command in c#, 
this is the command:

```
C:\Program Files\<reviewToolName>\review.exe --url <reviewTool-url> admin review-xml reviewno > C:\review.xml
```

this is what i have tried,

```
ProcessStartInfo proc = new ProcessStartInfo();
proc.CreateNoWindow = false;
proc.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\<reviewToolName>\review.exe";
proc.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
proc.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
proc.Arguments = "--url <reviewTool-url> admin review-xml " + reviewno.ToString() + " > C:\\review.xml;
Process.Start(proc);
```

but i'm getting error as xml file is not created
anybody please help me!!

Comment: i'm redirecting all the command output to review.xml file....this is working command

Comment: Redirect to file is a shell thing, you may use `cmd` /c for that otherwise just redirect output by yourself (check `Process.StandardOutput`).

Comment: Question marked as dupe is **one of many** examples of this.

Comment: Hi Adriano, i understand upto proc.Start() part! let me know how to redirect it xml file, as this command [C:\Program Files\<reviewToolName>\review.exe --url <reviewTool-url> admin review-xml reviewno > C:\review.xml] is working fine

Comment: It's all described there, in MSDN and in few hundred articles online...

Answer (score -1):

Insert actual URL under review in place of placeholder `<reviewTool-url>`